# Angular js - Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a project in angular 1.2, I have a problem with utf-8 encoding and the angular binding, some chars like "ñ" throw an error:

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control " ng-model="IdDesempeño">
```

**Angular error**

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character

I've got a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wlkPEKHS7TWE83ygXYL?p=preview)

Do you have any idea what's going on?

The [angular **error** doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%C3%B1%5D&p2=%C3%B1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wider the range of characters allowed in AngularJs identifiers to match your requirements.  This is done by modifying the `isIdent` function in `angular.js` file, around line 9730. I did this to allow French special characters and some more.

```
isIdent: function(ch) {
    return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ||
            'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ||
            '_' === ch || ch === '$') || 
            129 <= ch.charCodeAt(0) && ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 496; // added this line
```

There is an old pull request on Github for this (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4747).

Answer (score -1):

Variables can't contain "ñ".

The JSON model was misspelled.

Remember to put the script in the  and your page will be a little faster.

Look better in the syntax AngularJS.

I learning AngularJS too

you did fork on Plunker, see it.

SUERTE!