# Add an attribute to an object with different kind of accent in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

my usecase is:

I have a ng-model "myModel". I'm pulling the html for a form via ajax (because I have dynamic fields) and in it, the fields are described with:

```
<input ng-model="myModel.myField" name="myField">
```

This works perfectly except when the name of the field has an accent in it (it is all sent in utf8 though).I get the following:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr]
```

Is there any way to keep the accent in angular? myModel.fieldWithéèöüäà etc..

Edit: Solution provided in [Angular js - Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093660/angular-js-error-parselexerr-lexer-error) is a monkey patch for angular. I'm not going to add most of all unicode alphabet by hand. Is that the only solution?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular js - Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093660/angular-js-error-parselexerr-lexer-error)

Comment: Yeah but I feel like monkey patching Angular is far from a good and maintainable solution. The pull request is still pending.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the `obj['prop name']` syntax to access the values.

For instance, based on the plnkr that the other question referenced, you could use `<select class="form-control " ng-model="vm['IdDesempeño']">`, or also this way `<option ng-repeat="e in escala" value="{{e['IdDesempeño']}}">{{e.Significado}}</option>`.

You can see the original plunkr modified to work here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QNdSIxro2VxS131BMhm6?p=preview

Comment: I need to get that working by changing the module I'm using (django-angular) which outputs for now model.field. If it works, I'll mark your answer as the right one. =) Thks